# Filter com AngularJs e Gulp

Tags: angularjs, gulp

Estou criando um filtro para o angular utilizando o compilador *Gulp* entretanto estou tendo um erro e ao analisar o código compilado parece que está compilando algo errado, o que poderia ser?

Filtro:

```
class StrSplit extends Filter
  contructor: ->
    return (str, splitChar, splitIndex)->
      return '' unless str
      str.split(splitChar)[splitIndex]
```

View:

```
{{mystr | strSplit:',':0}}
```

Filtro compilado:

```
StrSplit = (function() {
  function StrSplit() {}
  StrSplit.prototype.contructor = function() {
    return function(str, splitChar, splitIndex) {
      if (!str) {
        return '';
      }
      return str.split(splitChar)[splitIndex];
    };
  };
  return StrSplit;
})();
angular.module('ng-utils').filter('strSplit', [StrSplit]);
```

Erro encontrado:

> Can't interpolate: 
>   2 - {{text_filter | strSplit:',':0}}
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olha como "constructor" é incorreto.

```
class StrSplit extends Filter
  constructor: ->
    return (str, splitChar, splitIndex) ->
      return '' unless str
      str.split(splitChar)[splitIndex]
```

Comment: Muito obrigado.